# @media in my HTML isn't working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The `@media` rules aren't making the different PHP pages appear and disappear. Am I doing it wrong? Also is there a better way of doing this?

This is the style within my index page and it's contained in the `<head>`. I'm also using external style sheets but I didn't think it'd be necessary to include them.

```
<style type="text/css">
<!-- Show Normal -->
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) {

div#show-normal { display:block; }

div#show-mobile { display:none; }

}

<!-- Show Mobile -->
@media only screen and ((min-height : 320px) and (max-device-width : 667px)) {

div#show-normal { display:none; }

div#show-mobile { display:block; }

}
</style>
```

This is all of the contents of my body tag

```
<body>

<!-- Default -->
<div id="show_normal">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <?php
        include("pages/default/header.php");
    ?>  

    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div id="contentContainer">
    <?php
        include ("pages/default/infoStrip.php");
        include ("pages/default/productStrip.php");
        include ("pages/default/slideshowStrip.php");
        include ("pages/default/footer.php");
    ?>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Mobile -->
<div id="show_mobile">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <?php
        include("pages/mobile/header.php");
    ?>  

    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div id="contentContainer">
    <?php
        include ("pages/mobile/infoStrip.php");
        include ("pages/mobile/productStrip.php");
        include ("pages/mobile/slideshowStrip.php");
        include ("pages/mobile/footer.php");
    ?>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you specified a `<meta name="viewport"... />`in your pages `<head></head>` section? See this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) article for more information...

Comment: By any chance `min-height : 320px` supposed to be `min-width : 320px`? And you are missing viewport meta.

Comment: This is not a good practice. Media queries in CSS only change what's shown, not what's rendered by the server. Your content is repeated in the "normal" and "mobile" divs. I would suggest going back to the drawing board and not presenting different HTML depending on the browser. Both browsers are downloading all of the content. `@media` should be used to make your design responsive, not to completely swap out page content.

Comment: I'll start learning meta tags and using viewports. Also if I wanted to load different pages depending on the screen size should I use javascript or PHP?

Answer (score 2):

the closing parenthesis after

```
(max-device-width : 667px)
```

is missing

or better: take out one of the opening parenthesis in

```
((min-height : 320px)
```